# Doctrine2 DQL issue with COUNT = 0

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have the following query so far:

```
   $shopQuery = $qb->select('DISTINCT u')
                    ->from("BlahUserBundle:User", 'u')
                    ->innerJoin('u.followers', 'followers')
                    ->andWhere('followers.id != :userId')
                    ->setParameter('userId', $user->getId())
                    ->orWhere('') //or where those user who doesn't have a follower yet
                    //->setMaxResults(5)
                    ;
```

I am trying to find a way to query all users who doesn't have a follower and whose follower is not my self (in this case my self is `$user->getId()`). How do I do so?

Comment: If you use an innerJoin you won't get the result you want because, if a user doesn't have a follower you won't get that row. I think you need a subQuery for this. Let me think about it :)

Comment: @Pi Wi is right, but you may replace your inner join by a left join to match both results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$shopQuery = $qb->from("BlahUserBundle:User", 'u')
            ->leftJoin(
                'u.followers',
                'followers',
                'on',
                'followers.id != :userId'
            )
            ->where('followers.id IS NULL')
            ->setParameter('userId', $user->getId());
$shopQuery->getQuery()->getResults();
```